# How can I import a vCard without getting duplicated fields?

Tags: iphone, contacts, import

The vCard format has a `UID` field which should uniquely identify a contact to avoid duplicates. This works: when importing the same vCard twice with multiple contacts inside and a fixed `UID` for each, it will recognize the ones that already exist and not add duplicates.

However, iOS contacts will duplicate all fields inside the contact: the phone number and email address of this contact will be there twice. Both the field label (work phone number, for example) and its value are identical.

The format also has a revision (`REV`) field but this appears to be unused. Importing a vCard with the same `REV` value twice, which should indicate that the data hasn't changed in the meantime, the fields are still being duplicated.

The `REV` and `UID` fields are not exported when sharing a contact, making me suspect that iOS doesn't take them into account at all.

The only solution that I see is that the exporter, the creator of the vCard file, needs to somehow know per device which fields already exist and omit those from the file. Updating a field does not seem to be possible at all.

Is there any way to create a vCard that will ignore already-existent fields or, even better, update them if they changed? I have not been able to find *any* documentation regarding Apple's handling of vCard files on iOS.